# How to make consecutive API calls in C#

Tags: c#, api, json.net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a program that makes a web API call and returns a JSON response. From that JSON response, I need to get the `Self` link and make another call to that endpoint and return that JSON response automatically.

After my initial request, I may need to repeat this process 2-3 times to get to the final endpoint I am looking for.

[JSON response from the first API call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUEV2.png)

```cs
public void makeRequestCall()
{
    //Making call with base API plus desired endpoint parameters
    string url = Consts.getURL;

    //iniatialize HttpClient, set credentials, and make call
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Consts.getURL);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Consts.Username + ":" + Consts.Password)));
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
    
    // Get the response and print it
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var callResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        //deserialize the JSON response
        callResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(callResult).ToString();
        
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(callResult);
        Console.WriteLine(callResult);       
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Create a different client for each request :  HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient(); HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient(); HttpClient client3 = new HttpClient();

Comment: If I get it right you are doing a request -> read the selfUrl and then try to do another request to this URL and do this several times right? Is your question how to do this with one (or more) HttpClient(s) or how to do a sequence of requests?

Comment: How to do a sequence of requests

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. The way to do a series of requests is to (1) write code for the first request, (2) write code for the second request, (3) write code for the third request, then (4) execute the code that calls them in order. It's that simple. What exactly are you having trouble with? Were you hoping for some library or utility that would automatically do it for you?

Comment: Please make your method async and forget the usage of `.Result`

Answer (score 1):

You can use some wrapper around to do your API request(s). But lets start from the beginning.

### The service which uses `HttpClient`

---

```cs
class MyService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly string _username = "";
    private readonly string _password = "";
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyService(HttpClient client, ILogger<MyService> logger)
    {
        _client = client;
        _logger = logger;

        // Setup your credentials & headers. 
        // Do not store _password in plain text its just for demo purpose!
        //
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_username + ":" + _password)));
    }

    public async Task MakeRequestCallsAsync()
    {
        // Do your first request. In this case to a dummy API
        //
        var request1 = await ExecuteNextRequestAsync<object, ResponseObject>(null!, (input) =>
        {
            return "https://dummyjson.com/products";
        });

        // Do your second request with the result of your first one
        //
        var request2 = await ExecuteNextRequestAsync<ResponseObject, ResponseProduct>(request1, (input) =>
        {
            return "https://dummyjson.com/products/" + input.Products.ElementAt(0).Id;
        });
        
        // And so on just by using the response of a previous request...
        //
    }

    private async Task<TOut> ExecuteNextRequestAsync<TIn, TOut>(TIn lastResponse, Func<TIn, string> factory)
    {
        var url = factory(lastResponse);
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            _logger.LogInformation($"{responseJson}");

            var responseObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TOut>(responseJson);
            return responseObj;
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError($"{response.StatusCode}");
            return default;
        }
    }
}
```

### Register your service(s)

---

This example is using `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly` to register a `HttpClient` per service implementation [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly)

```cs
// In your `Startup.cs` or if you are using > NET 6 in your `Program.cs`
services.AddHttpClient<MyService>()
        .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))  
        .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
services.AddScoped<MyService>();
```

```cs
static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));
}
```

> **Important:** `MyService` calls APIs based on a response object which can be set manually or used from a deserialized response of a previous call.
> But it always uses the same `Authorization`-header.

---

A working dotnetfiddle [example can be found here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tMwprK)

Comment: Thank you. Only thing I am still struggling with is getting the second link from the JSON file. It seems as if my issue would be on line 70 of the dotnetfiddle you included. I have created a new post for this as well! Thank you again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965170/how-to-get-value-inside-of-json-array!

Comment: Updating the original question is the better approach here I think.

Comment: About you second question. I think I did not understand your problem. Is there a json convert issue or what exactly is the exception saying?